# Proxy server troubles with lxc-create in 16.04-lts

Tags: apt, proxy, lxc

I am trying to create a new ubuntu lxc container using lxc-create but I am having issues with a proxy server significantly into ( > 1000 lines ) the creation of the container.

```
lxc-create -n demo_cont1  -t ubuntu  --logfile=demo_cont1.txt  --logpriority=DEBUG
```

gives this output:

```
...
...    
1119  Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
1120  Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
1121  Err:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
1122  403  Use Proxy Server
...
...
1251  Reading package lists... Done
1252  W: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.
1253  N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
1254  N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

The debug log is:

```
 lxc-create 20171212070515.944 ERROR    lxc_container - lxccontainer.c:create_run_template:1295 - container creation template for demo_cont1 failed
 lxc-create 20171212070515.946 INFO     lxc_container - lxccontainer.c:container_destroy:2396 - Destroyed rootfs for demo_cont1
 lxc-create 20171212070515.946 INFO     lxc_container - lxccontainer.c:container_destroy:2412 - Destroyed directory for demo_cont1
 lxc-create 20171212070515.946 ERROR    lxc_create_ui - tools/lxc_create.c:main:318 - Error creating container demo_cont1
```

I have told ubuntu about the proxy server by:

1. export http_proxy=< proxy settings >  in the shell.
2. Acquire::http::Proxy ""  in /etc/apt/apt.conf
3. http_proxy = < proxy settings > in /etc/wgetrc

apt-get and wget appear to work fine manually and download what would appear to be hundreds of packages prior to the error in lxc-create.

Is there another proxy setting? The system does not have a firewall and has a fixed routable IP address.

Is there a way to understand what is different about that request than the others?